# "No module named" when importing from another package in python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

If I execute `demo2.py` it works fine, the problem is when I execute `main.py`

```
|myPackage
   |subPackage
      demo.py
      demo2.py
   main.py
```

main.py

```
from ludikDriver.demo2 import demo2_print

demo2_print()
```

demo2.py

```
from demo import demoprint

def demo2_print():
    print("demo2")
    demoprint()

demo2_print()
```

demo.py

```
def demoprint():
    print("demo")
```

Error:`No module named 'demo'`

Answer (score 1):

Just use relative imports as suggested in [pep 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

```
from .demo import demoprint
```

You can do for the other package. Just as relative paths.

Comment: but if I do this I can´t execute demo2.py alone. It is posible?

Comment: No because you say to python you need to import the following task before run the code. There are some hacky ways to accomplish this, but i didn't would suggest this.

Answer (score 1):

Your modules need context of themselves. You should have the "__init__.py" file in ***subPackage*** and ***myPackage***. Then your import should be relative:

```
from . import demo
```

OR more in context of your example:

```
from .demo import demoprint
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is associated with the top line in demo.py:

> from demo import demoprint

There is no module named demo